# Bootstrap image display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */

.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
/* PORTFOLIO PAGE CSS 
---------------------------------------------------*/

.css-img div {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  .nav > li > a:hover,
  .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
  .nav > li.disabled > a {
    color: #777777;
  }
  .nav > li.disabled > a:hover,
  .nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .nav .open > a,
  .nav .open > a:hover,
  .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #337ab7;
  }
  .nav .nav-divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  .nav > li > a > img {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
      float: left;
    }
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    overflow-x: visible;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
      width: auto;
      border-top: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: block !important;
      height: auto !important;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
      overflow-y: visible;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
  }
  @media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
      max-height: 200px;
    }
  }
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container > .navbar-header, .container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-brand:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .navbar-brand > img {
    display: block;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: static;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <!-- link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" -->

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->

<body>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="css-img">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am building a template so I can create a Wordpress theme and want to display the images on my portfolio page as horizontal and not vertical like they are now. I set the div to display inline-block and it was working until I added text below the header. How can I fix this? I may have to repost this since it wont let me add the core Bootstrap code to the fiddle without giving me a warning. So my header is missing code for it to work properly here but it works fine with all the Bootstrap files I have with the code on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing each `col-md-*` in a separate `row`. Naturally, Bootstrap `row`s are stacked vertically.

You should place all your `col-md-*`s in a single `row`.

Comment: Yes that was the trick! Something else to remember when working with Bootstrap. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Making the caption div float:left and removing the inline-block from .ccs-img div rule will solve your problem.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/*NEW*/
img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */

.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
/* PORTFOLIO PAGE CSS 
---------------------------------------------------*/

.css-img div {
  
}
/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  .nav > li > a:hover,
  .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
  .nav > li.disabled > a {
    color: #777777;
  }
  .nav > li.disabled > a:hover,
  .nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: not-allowed;
  }
  .nav .open > a,
  .nav .open > a:hover,
  .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #337ab7;
  }
  .nav .nav-divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  .nav > li > a > img {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
      float: left;
    }
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    overflow-x: visible;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
      width: auto;
      border-top: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: block !important;
      height: auto !important;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      overflow: visible !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
      overflow-y: visible;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
  }
  @media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
      max-height: 200px;
    }
  }
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container > .navbar-header, .container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-brand:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .navbar-brand > img {
    display: block;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: static;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 0;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->

<body>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="css-img">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/242x200" alt="placeholder image">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Was not quite what I was looking for on desktop layouts but I will use the code (or approach) you suggested so the images and text stack in smaller viewports. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful!